# Convert Default Dropbox Datastore to Shareable Datastore

Tags: dropbox-api

Up until now, I have been using `[[DBDatastoreManager sharedManager] openDefaultDatastore:nil]` (iOS) to open and use the default datastore in my users' Dropbox accounts. I now want to create an option for users to share their datastores.

The documentation indicates that:

> Datastores with shareable IDs are created using `DBDatastoreManager.createDatastore:` which allows them to be shared between users.

How do I convert my out-of-the-box use of the default datastore to a unique datastore ID as created by `createDatastore`? Do I have to create a new shareable datastore and copy all the data from the default datastore into it?

Comment: I think that yes, if you have existing data in a datastore with a non-shareable ID, you'll need to create a new datastore with a shareable ID and move the data over.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. I know shareable datastores came later than the rest of the API, but it would be nice if all datastores were shareable by default, and their unique IDs were different from their name/label (which would be what is displayed in the online datastore browser).

Comment: @smarx If you want to re-post your response as an answer, I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting as answer instead of comment: Yes, if you have existing data in a datastore with a non-shareable ID, you'll need to create a new datastore with a shareable ID and move the data over.